# How to use Google Tag Manager to track conversion value using output from a 3rd party script

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, bing

I am trying to create a user defined variable in GTM that will allow me to track ecommerce conversion values in BING Ads, and the only thing I have to work with is a 3rd party script that is outputting the following sample data into the "confirmation" page source code:

```
   <script>TrackConversionData={orderId:"668",orderAmount:"158",orderCurrency:"USD"}</script>
```

I'm confused as to what "Variable Type" to use from the list of GTM User-Defined Variables, if there even is one that would work here in this case, where I want to extract the variable value "orderAmount" from the output above, which appears on every successful order.

From there my guess is that it's pretty simple to set up a separate Bing Ads Universal Event Tracking tag for this.

Comment: Have you checked this help page? https://help.ads.microsoft.com/#apex/3/en/56894/-1

Comment: Yes - however, I don't have the ability to add code to this page, so I was hoping to use GTM to record variable values using what I could find currently in the source code of this page. Does that make sense?